# Statically add content to database in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and have a question about it's database.
I have a basic site in which I want to save and disply some basic details of a list of people. I created a model named Person and a controller named PersonController which has two basic methods :

```
def list
    @person = Person.find(:all)
end 

def show
    @person = Person.find(params[:id])
end
```

I also have a migrate file, declaring the field in each column in the table (for example - :name, :string :address, :string.)
My quetion is, how can I add my myself new people to the database, without and UI-form in the site? Currently there are none people in the list, and I, as a programmer, want to add them. How can it be done?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the rails console

with this commands:

at CMD:

```
Rails c

Person.create!(:name => "yourname", :email=> "youremail")
```

Now if you want to instance that method in the console you can do this:

```
@person = Person.last
@person.name
@person.email
```

or something like this:

```
@person = Person.find_by_email("youremail")
@person.name
@person.email
```

Comment: Thanks, but after doing this, when I write in consol "@person" it prints "nil", looks like the data was not added. Do I have to update the database with any console command?

Comment: Edited, if you found it helpfull dont forget to thumbs up and mark as answered, cheers